# How to create thumbnails/screenshots out of PDF files on my Linux server?

Tags: php, linux, pdf, screenshot, thumbnails

I want to create thumbnails out of PDF files to be able to display a short preview of the PDF file on a website.

I tried it by using ImageMagick. Unfortunately the results aren't very pleasing. 
The resulting images are very fuzzy.

Example Thumbnail (fuzzy):

[image: Bildschirmfoto 2010-09-11 um 22.57.49.png]

Original PDF: (see Comment)

Command: `convert -thumbnail x800 k.pdf[0] test.png`

Is my convert command misconfigured or do you know any better way achieving my goal?

Comment: Original PDF: http://cl.ly/2aaeab1848c0fc5db5ce

Answer (score 8):

Your original pdf is smaller than the thumbnail you're creating. Imagemagick scales the image to match the requested dimensions. Use the following parameters:

```
convert -scale '800x800+0+0>' -colorspace rgb -strip in.pdf[0] out.png
```

The trailing `>` in the scale parameter tells Imagemagick to not scale the image to larger than the original.

**Edit:** Imagemagick uses Ghostscript to render PDF files. You can use Ghostscript directly if you need to set some parameters, like resolution to get a better image. Default resolution is 72 DPI which means that an A4 paper has size of 595 x 841 pixels. With 150 DPI you'll get twice the number of pixels. E.g.

```
gs -q -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pngalpha -dMAxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixles=0 -dGridFitTT=0 -r150x150 -sOutputFile=out.png in.pdf
```

The above command is almost identical to the one Imagemagick uses. Note the -r parameter which sets 150 DPI resolution. You can use ImageMagick to scale the resulting image to smaller size.

Using a higher resolution will reduce fuzziness when you resize the image.

Comment: Thanks! But there is still a huge difference. PDF: http://cl.ly/2aafb79d30d263fe783b Image: http://cl.ly/f76642c45fbd45532789

Comment: I updated the answer with the GS command to get a better resolution image from your pdf. Note that the PDF screencapture and resulting image are of different size. If I convert the first image to the same width as the second image has, the resulting image is equally fuzzy. You can reduce fuzziness (some) by using a higher resolution source image. It also helps if you'll be creating 800 pixel wide images, since A4 at 72 DPI is 595 pixels.

Comment: Beware also, that Imagemagick scales images badly by default, possibly resulting in further degradation.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use Google Docs.

```
https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=bi&pagenumber=1&url=http://.../sample.pdf
```