# How can I create a link to a PDF document and display a thumbnail preview of the document?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

So, this is sort of a strange question.

I am trying to create a research/writing portfolio on my website. My goal is to display a small "thumbnail" image of the PDF (like a thumbnail of an image) and then link to a pop-out that will display the PDF text with page flip-through capability (like amazon does for previewing pages in a book). I could just use an image file for the thumbnail and link to the PDF, but I am having issues getting this to work correctly since the layout I am using has a "Maginifier" tool to open portfolio samples rather than a link-out and I prefer to have a pop-out preview, as I mentioned before.

This is for the now-empty "Portfolio" section of my website www.lyndajoygerry.com

Thank you!

Best,
Lynda Joy Gerry

Comment: This is a very basic question, just use an HTML link around a thumbnail image on your website that links to the PDF files, most computers/browsers these days will automatically open it up for anyone who clicks the link to view it in Adobe Reader.

Comment: Yes, but this is not my issue. I don't just want to link to the PDF; I want it to "lightbox" open a preview. Also, how do I create a thumbnail for the PDF? I don't want to just use the Acrobat PDF icon; I want a sample image of the PDF.

Comment: If you have access to a Linux server and/or PHP there are other questions on Stack overflow asking how to create a thumbnail from a PDF: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692654/how-to-create-thumbnails-screenshots-out-of-pdf-files-on-my-linux-server?rq=1 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467793/how-do-i-convert-a-pdf-document-to-a-preview-image-in-php If you don't then there might be online tools that can do this for you.